# Page lag from css

Tags: css, html

I have a template but when I scroll down the page it seems to be really lagging
I have a 8 core computer with 8gb of ram so I know it ent my computer. I have had other users telling me that my site is running slow. I change my layout and all works fine so I know its not the server. I change my html layout and put all my php scripts onto a new html / css layout and works fine with no lag but I like this layout...

Here is my css which i think is the problem

```
html
{
    background: url(../images/background.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

div.container
{   
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
}
div.holder
{
    width:990px;
    background-color:#d7f7f7;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    background-image:url('../images/swampertbackground.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom center;
}
#container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #d7f7f7;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-left: solid #25a5a6 2px;
    border-right: solid #25a5a6 2px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
div.banner
{
    height:125px;
    width:700px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-left:140px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border: solid #25a5a6 1px;
    background-image:url('../images/banner.png');
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
}

ul , li
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;

}
div.left_navigation
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:150px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
    width: 152px;
}

div.left_navigation2
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:300px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
}

div.left_navigation3
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:400px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
}
div.left_navigation4
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:500px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
}
div.left_navigation5
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:600px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
}

div.left_navigation6
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:700px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
}

li.header
{
    width:150px;
    height:14px;
    background-color:#54c0c1;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    background-image:url('../images/header.png');
    border-left:2px #188c8d solid;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:900;

}
li.links
{
    width:150px;
    height:16px;
    background-color:#c1f9fa;
    border-bottom:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-left:2px #188c8d solid;
    border-right:1px #188c8d solid;
    color:#074647;

}

li.links:hover
{
    background-color:#FFFF00;
    color:#296584;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #0096ff;

}
li.footer
{
    width:150px;
    height:9px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
    background-image:url('../images/header.png');
    border-bottom:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-left:2px #188c8d solid;
    border-right:1px #188c8d solid;
}
div.centerboxholder
{   
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    margin-left:165px;
    width:661px;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
}
div.centerbox
{   
    position:absolute;
    width:661px;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px; 
}
li.chead
{
    width:660px;
    height:14px;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    background-image:url('../images/header.png');
    border-left:2px #188c8d solid;
    border-right:1px #188c8d solid;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:900;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #4b8384;
}

li.ccontent
{
    width:659px;
    background-color:#c1f9fa;
    border-bottom:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-left:2px #188c8d solid;
    color:#000;
    font-size:0.9em;
    border-right:1px #188c8d solid;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
}
li.cfoot
{
    width:659px;
    height:9px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
    background-image:url('../images/header.png');
    border-bottom:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-left:2px #188c8d solid;
    border-right:1px #188c8d solid;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
}

div.right_navigation
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:834px;
    top:150px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #4b8384;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
}

table
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
}

td
{
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}

#textfield
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e2fffc;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#gender
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e2fffc;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:110px;
    padding:0px;
}
#gendertop
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e2fffc;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;

}
#genderbottom
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e2fffc;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
}

#button
{
    background-color:Transperent;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e2fffc;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    width:100px;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:16px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#Avatar
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e2fffc;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:110px;
}
#changer
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e2fffc;
    border-bottom:1px #188c8d solid;


}

li.topper
{   
    height:12px;
    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    background-image:url('../images/header.png');
}
li.bottomer
{

    border:1px #188c8d solid;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    background-image:url('../images/header.png');
    height:12px;
}

#button:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
a:link { color:#296584; text-decoration:none;display:block;}
a:visited { color:#296584; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover { color:#296584; text-decoration:none;text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #0096ff;}
a:active {color:#296584; text-decoration:none; background-color:}
```

Is there anything in that css which will make it lag ?

it says here 
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=pokemontoxic.net&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

i have 81 errors are these big errors ?

Comment: Hello,you should correct your errors with the validator (ignore unknown property ones) : http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator . What are the sizes of your images ?

Comment: im getting 81 errors   http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=pokemontoxic.net&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: Try running it through a CSS profiler: http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/

Comment: It's unlikely, but it could be that background.png et al are very very large.

Answer (score 3):

Use this tool to stress test your css, the author had issues with border radius on large elements: http://andy.edinborough.org/CSS-Stress-Testing-and-Performance-Profiling

Answer (score 0):

border-radius has been shown to be process intensive, in one browser specifically, I think it was Firefox. With position:fixed, I can see those as being your only two problem areas, especially with the number of radius properties you have. Whether that is enough to cause you problems you would notice, I don't know.

Comment: You're also using text-shadow

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so.
check how much 'heavy' are your images; Use png if you want transparency if not, convert it to jpg that are lighter.

one thing you can check with chrome is the unused styles:

press F12, in Audits tab and then click to the Run button. And in inform you can see the things that you dont use.

You can minimize the css (for example with [this](http://tools.w3clubs.com/cssmin/))

And the last you can add gzip compression

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Your background seems to be a large png, and you're using absolute positioning to place the page contents on top of a still background. I've seen this cause issues before with scrolling lag. Change:

```
position:absolute;
```

To:

```
position:relative;
```

In div.container and as mentioned before scale down your images. At least begin by making the HTML tag background image a jpeg.